# D3D texture to NVIDIA Media Foundation Encoder

Tags: video, nvidia, video-encoding, ms-media-foundation

I want to encode a ARGB D3D11 texture by the NVIDIA H.264 Encoder MFT directly.But i found this MFT's input type must YUV format like NV12. So i have to map texture to memory then transform to NV12.Is there any way can avoid memory copying?Or how can i transform a ARGB texture to NV12 texture no memory copy?

Answer (score 0):

What type of media buffers "NVIDIA H.264 Encoder MFT" accept ?

1 - Use the underlying Direct3D surface. (Applies only to video frames stored in Direct3D surfaces.)

2 - Use the IMF2DBuffer interface.

3 - Use the IMFMediaBuffer interface.

See : [Uncompressed Video Buffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/medfound/uncompressed-video-buffers)

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia's MFT could be definitely better. They don't allow ARGB input even though hardware is capable in general. You can use [Video Processor MFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/video-processor-mft) to convert the pixel format (on GPU with decent performance).